# Excel to SQL and Handling Duplicate Values

Tags: python, sql, r, data-manipulation

Lookup Table in Worksheet 1.

```
ID      CODE  REASSIGN(CODE)
W12-05  AA    ZZ
W12-05  BB    ZZ
W14-01  CC    CC
W14-03  AA    AA
W15-01  DD    DD
W15-01  DD    DD
```

ID and CODE are generated from the report

REASSIGN(CODE) is what I am trying to accomplish. If there are multiple IDs (ex. W12-05) that are the same with different CODE values, then assign it to "ZZ" . However, if there are multiple IDs and they all have the same CODE values (ex. W15-01), then assign it to the same code value.

There are 2 Worksheets (Worksheet 2 and Worksheet 3) that house the ID and different data associated with that ID.

Data Table:

```
ID      LOOKUP REASSIGN(CODE)
W12-05  ZZ
W14-01  CC
W14-03  AA
W15-01  DD
```

How can I accomplish the REASSIGN(CODE) column in the first table? Something along the lines of:

If IDs duplicate and multiple different CODEs, assign to ZZ.
If IDs duplicate and same codes, assign to same CODE.

There might be instances where if there certain multiple codes for duplicate IDs, it will need to assign to a specific CODE. "ZZ" is the default when I don't know where it should go and it can be handled by another department. Sometimes I know that code "EE" and code "FF" belong to one department and there is logic to assign it to "GG" for example.

I want to combine all 3 Worksheets based on the ID column and I want all the data from Worksheet 2 and Worksheet 3 to be there, even if there isn't a match in IDs. Worksheet 1 will be used just as a lookup to pull in the REASSIGN(CODE).

Please let me know if I need to explain further or if there are any questions. I am open to ideas and other solutions, since this is just the logic that came into my head. I am not sure if it's better to create another table for the REASSIGN(CODE) or if my logic is sound.

> Original Question - RESOLVED
>
> Combination of IF, REPLACE, and & - I am happy to provide more details.
>
> I have 3 workbooks I am pulling data from and I do perform some data
>   manipulation.
>
> Here are the formulas I currently have in my spreadsheet:
>
> Column: OB
>
> Formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@[OBN]]," ",""),"-","")`
>
> This cleans up the OBN column removing all hyphens and spaces to
>   standardize it based on the data table.
>
> Column: DO
>
> Formula:
>
> ```
> =IF(OR([@[DON]]="NA",ISBLANK(TRIM([@[DON]])),[@[DON]]="N/A",ISNA([@[DON]]),ISBLANK([@[DON]])),"",[@[DON]])
> ```
>
> This makes the DO column blank if there is no value there or if it's
>   NA or N/A, as that is how the report displays it. Otherwise, use the
>   value of DON as DO.
>
> Column: OB+DO (This is the ID in the tables below)
>
> Formula:
>
> ```
> =IF([@DO]="",[@OB],CONCATENATE([@OB],"-",[@DO]))
> ```
>
> Concatenate columns OB and DO with a hyphen if DO contains a value
>   that is not NA or N/A. Otherwise, just use OB.

Answer (score 2):

I had to move to SQL since Excel was not handling the data very well. I have it fully functioning now in SQL. If anyone is curious on the solution, I have posted it below.

`SELECT [Table1].[ID], [Table1].[CODE], Count([Table1].[CODE]) AS [CODE Count]
FROM [Table1]
GROUP BY [Table1].[ID], [Table1].[CODE];`

I first do a count of CODE and group by ID and CODE. This gets me the count of each CODE per ID. For my example above, W12-05 would be listed twice and would have a count of 1 and 1, results in the table below.

Table2

```
ID  CODE    CODE Count
W12-05  AA  1
W12-05  BB  1
W14-01  CC  1
W14-03  AA  1
W15-01  DD  2
```

Then, I do a count of ID's and grouped by ID.

```
SELECT [Table1].[ID], Count([Table1].[ID]) AS [ID Count]
FROM [Table1]
GROUP BY [Table1].[ID];
```

Table3

```
ID  ID Count
W12-05  2
W14-01  1
W14-03  1
W15-01  2
```

This will get me the total count of each ID.

Next, I compare the ID count and CODE Count for each ID.

```
SELECT [Table2].[ID], [Table2].[CODE], [Table2].[CODE Count], [Table3].[Count ID]
FROM [Table2] LEFT JOIN [Table3] ON [Table2].[ID] = [Table3].[ID];
```

This yields the following table.

Table4

```
ID     CODE CODE Count  ID Count
W12-05  AA       1          2
W12-05  BB       1          2
W14-01  CC       1          1
W14-03  AA       1          1
W15-01  DD       2          2
```

The last step I do is compare the count of CODE and ID.

```
SELECT [Table4].[ID], [Table4].[CODE Count], [Table4].[Count ID], IIf([Table4].[CODE Count]<>[Table4].[Count ID],"ZZ", [Table4].CODE) AS CODE
FROM [Table4];
```

If the CODE Count and ID Count do not match, assign it to "ZZ".

Table5

```
ID    CODE Count  ID Count  CODE
W12-05    1            2     ZZ
W12-05    1            2     ZZ
W14-01    1            1     CC
W14-03    1            1     AA
W15-01    2            2     DD
```

From here, you can just take the DISTINCT values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Table5].[ID], [Table5].CODE
FROM [Table5];

ID     CODE
W12-05  ZZ
W14-01  CC
W14-03  AA
W15-01  DD
```

I am not sure if this is the optimal way, but it is a working solution for me. I hope this helps!

Comment: I was just browsing and found your explanation intriguing. +1 For the effort. If you import your excel as a table in a database like Mysql or Postgresql, it should be pretty straightforward, I assume. Basically, assuming your table is called excel_table and the columns imported are id and code, then you can get your desired results with the following query: "select id, case when max(coalesce(code,'')) = min(coalesce(code,'')) then max(coalesce(code,'')) else 'ZZ' END as reassign_code  from excel_table group by id".

Comment: I did not get a notification for this comment! I will have to test your solution out tomorrow and see if I can figure out what exactly it is doing. It seems like you are making all the null values blank with coalesce. I don't fully understand how the max and min work in your solution. Would you not need to group by both ID and CODE? Would you mind explaining the logic behind your solution? It is much more efficient than mine so I would like to learn from it. @softdevlife

Comment: There are a lot of use cases where comparing nulls can be useful, but if you can avoid them with specifying a dummy value i.e. blank (especially when you use those columns as conditional joins between tables), you will be saving a lot of trouble. Inspired by the inventor of relational databases Edgar F. Codd, the book "SQL Relational Theory" by C.J. Date Chapter 4 "No Duplicates, No Nulls" discusses more about that. A great resource I have found that explains SQL concepts well (including group by aggregations) is https://selectstarsql.com/

Comment: @softdevlife sorry for the late reply! I am using MS Access and coalesce is not a available. Would Nz() or Is Null() be a valid alternative? I am still trying to understand your solution :)

Comment: Yes, although not using Microsoft Access since my college days, reading from an article https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php seems you can replace NZ with Coalesce from the above code. MS Access is very limited in my opinion. MySQL and especially PostgreSQL are better environments to write SQL queries. Don't have the time to write a blog about it, but I would say practice and picking the right workplace environment and challenges will make you better at intuitively wrangling data with SQL.

Comment: You are awesome! I am going to check out the resource more in detail that you linked. At home I am able to use MySQL, it's just challenging in other environments.